# Graph using python-igraph with attributes per node and attributes per edges

Tags: graph, python-3.5, igraph

I'm trying to create a graph using the Python-Igraph library. Each node would have attributes, for example, In a graph of books the nodes They would be books and the attributes of these nodes would be:

```
Title: title_name
Synopsis: book_description
Author: author_name
Preface: preface
```

And all these attributes of the nodes would have edges
Linking to similar attributes from other nodes
 Containing the weight of similarity between these attributes. Thus each node would have 4 edges for another node.
I'm using python 3 and igraph.

The way I'm implementing it is as follows:

```
    g = Graph()
    g.vs["Title"] = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
    g.vs["Synopsis"] = ["synopsis1", "synopsis2", "synopsis3"]
    g.vs["Author"] = ["author1", "author2", "author3"]
    g.vs["Preface"] = ["preface1", "preface2", "preface3"]
```

Now how to put the link between them ?  I know it is used `g.es` But Igraph's site is a bit vague about that. Thanks

Comment: I had wrote an extense answer to this in pt.stackoverflow.com -  if that answer is not clear noguh, you could care to comment it there.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202186/grafo-usando-o-python-igraph-com-atributos-por-n%C3%B3-e-arestas/202211#202211

Comment: Thank you! I'm the same person XD